# Adding dependency to NSIS installer

Tags: windows, installation, dependencies, nsis

I have created an NSIS installer.Just wanted to know how to add dependency
Eg the installer should not run on windows Xp etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

```
!include WinVer.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
    ${If} ${IsWinXP} ; or use ${AtMostWinXP} instead
        MessageBox MB_OK "Does not work on XP"
        Quit
    ${Else}
         MessageBox MB_OK "Looking good, sir!"
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```